# Deferred tasks: Reference turning null after a while automatically

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have written a Deferred task to be executed when the server starts. Here is the ContextListener where the endpoints eventually execute the task:

```
public class ServerSetupListenerVer1 implements ServletContextListener {


    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //Endpoint service
        final LearnerProfileVer2PersistenceEndpoint learnerEndpoint = new LearnerProfileVer2PersistenceEndpoint();
        final TutorProfileVer2PersistenceEndpoint tutorEndpoint = new TutorProfileVer2PersistenceEndpoint();

        //Retrieve the dummy profile data
        final LearnerProfileVer1[] learnerProfiles = (LearnerProfileVer1[]) ProfileUtils.getJSONToProfiles(STATUS_LEARNER);
        final TutorProfileVer1[] tutorProfiles = (TutorProfileVer1[]) ProfileUtils.getJSONToProfiles(STATUS_TUTOR);

        //Insert this data into the datastore
        ObjectifyService.run(new VoidWork() {
            @Override
            public void vrun() {
                for(LearnerProfileVer1 profile : learnerProfiles){
                    learnerEndpoint.insert(profile);
                }
                for(TutorProfileVer1 profile : tutorProfiles){
                    tutorEndpoint.insert(profile);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }
}
```

You can see that there are 2 endpoints that I am keeping references to here. Both of these endpoints have the Deferred task in common to execute. Following is the deferred task:

```
static class LocationTask implements DeferredTask {

        private Account acc;
        private LatLng geoCoordinates;
        private int retries = 0;

        public LocationTask(final Account acc, final LatLng geoCoordinates) {
            logger.info("Profile at the time of task creation: " + acc.getProfile());
            this.acc = acc;
            this.geoCoordinates = geoCoordinates;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            logger.info("Profile at the time of DeferredTask.run() call " + acc.getProfile());
            String response = LocationUtil.getFormattedAddress(geoCoordinates);

            if((response = checkResponseCode(response)) != null){
                // Stash the address into the Datastore
                logger.info("Profile to be updated with location-info: " + acc.getProfile());
                acc.setLocationInfo(new Account.LocationInfo(response));
                ofy().save().entity(acc).now();
            }
        }
        private String checkResponseCode(String response){
            if(response == null){
                return null;
            }
            if(response.equals("ZERO_RESULTS")){
                return null;
            }
            else if(response.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT")){
                // We can re-request without any GET params except the LatLng
                if(retries ++ == 1){
                    return null;
                }
                return checkResponseCode(LocationUtil.getFormattedAddress(geoCoordinates, null));
            }
            else if(response.equals("REQUEST_DENIED")){
                return null;
            }
            else if(response.equals("INVALID_REQUEST")){
                return null;
            }
            else if(response.equals("UNKNOWN_ERROR")){
                return null;
            }
            else{
                return response;
            }

        }
    }
```

Basically, these endpoints insert an Account into the Datastore using Objectify but just before insertion of Account, I wanted that to calculate the address from {Latitude, Longitude} using a deferred task. The problem is that the reference to the profile inside of the Account class vanishes at the time the task is executed. I confirmed this through the log statements. The log statement in the constructor of Deferred task prints the contents of the profile but the same profile is null when the logged from the `run()` method.

Surprising thing is that the `LatLng geoCoordinates` param is alive and it was retrieved from inside of the profile itself. Only the fields that I am not directly referencing(through params) are not alive. I was wondering if this has to do with serialization of the task...

Also note that the tasks start executing after the endpoint requests(1500 at once) are taken care of.

Also, a new task is created for each Account creation as follows:

```
void scheduleLocationInfoUpdation(final Account acc, final LatLng geoCoordinates){
        if(geoCoordinates == null){
            return;
        }
        //Using a deferred task
        Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
        queue.addAsync(TaskOptions.Builder.withPayload(new LocationTask(acc, geoCoordinates)));
    }
```

This is a really weird scenario. Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it turns out its because of Serialization. I made all my model classes implement Serializable and now the references are alive.